# BeanCreationException with Springboot, Swagger and Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, swagger

I have a Springboot application(**v1.5.2**) with a dependency that itself is a Springboot application(**v1.5.2**), and when I try to document the first application with Swagger(**springfox v2.7.0**) like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
```

It blows up when I start the application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [xx/xx/restx/common/config/ObjectMapperConfigurer.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'objectMapperConfigurer'; factory method 'jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at xx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.service.XXXX.main(XXXX.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I remove the `@Configuration` annotation from the Swagger configuration it starts just fine.

I'm quite new to Spring and have no idea what's causing this. Could it be some sort of bean collision?

Comment: From the stacktrace: > No matching factory method found: factory bean 'objectMapperConfigurer'; factory method 'jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static. Have you done that ?

Comment: Yes, it exists and it is non-static.

Comment: is it public ? check if it's called by putting a log in it.

Comment: It is public. I will do a log from it tomorrow. Thanks.